# Can I explain a process of something in sentences without using "I"?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, subjects

I am creating a portfolio of design works, which illustrates how each project is made from start to finish. On each project's pages, there are graphic to guide people to read from left to right with a title for each step. There are also a short descriptions about 2-4 sentences accompany the titles.

Here is where I have my question. I know it is grammatically right to use 'I' and write this process in past tense but, it sounds less beautiful and long. I tried start the sentence with V-ing but then feels like it is grammatically wrong. Because this process has already happened in the past, may be I should put past tense but start sentences with V-ed sounds weird to me. As a portfolio of design work, I think it should be short and does not sound like "I'm" telling a story.

For example:
(Conceptualization Step)

> Explored possibilities to form a model using different materials and methods. Collected data from various research and made a conclusion of a prototype with team members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also speak of the work's project sections using the present tense:

> Explores different materials and methods for building a model.
>   A prototype is built with team members using research data.

Answer (score 2):

Passive voice changes the object of the sentence to the subject instead, which allows you to omit "I".

> *Explored* **possibilities** to form a model using different materials and methods. *Collected* **data** from various research and made a conclusion of a prototype with team members.

could instead be

> **Possibilities** were *explored* to form a model using different materials and methods. **Data** was *collected* from research, and a conclusion of the prototype was developed with the help of other team members/members of the team.

Conclusion of the prototype doesn't really make sense. "Development of the prototype was concluded" is better. This is because conclusion in this case means

> the end or finish of an event, process, or text.

which cannot apply to 'prototype'.

"Data collected from research", however, is nonsensical - of course data was collected from research - that's the whole point of research! So change this to "From our research".

Thus I would say:

> Possibilities were explored to form a model using different materials and methods. From our research, the development of the prototype was concluded with the help of other members of the team.

DrMoishe Pippik asserts that the passive voice is to be avoided. This is true for most cases, as the passive voice makes your writing weaker and less direct. However, it can be used when you want to emphasize an action itself and the doer of the action is irrelevant. This is the case for your portfolio. Everyone reading it knows it's yours, so there is no need to include yourself as the subject.

Comment: OMG!! This is so much helpful. Thank you. And, you are right! it does not make sense to use "I" in so many places since this is my portfolio. I think that is why I feel like not to use it. (I'm not an English native speaker tho but it just feel too many "I" for me.)